# Error when using DBCA to create database Oracle XE 18c

Tags: oracle, oracle-18c

I am trying to create a new database using dbca.
Windows 10.
Please help me to find solution.

[image: attributes]

[image: error]

Here is the [log](https://ghostbin.com/paste/ji9Fh)

Comment: What does the DBCA log show?

Comment: https://ghostbin.com/paste/ji9Fh

Answer (score 0):

Sorry it took me a while to get back to this. I see at least two major issues in the trace.log:

First, it appears your environment is misconfigured:

> [main] [ 2021-02-03 15:09:37.030 GMT+03:00 ] [StepContext.:429]
> Error initializing Network Configuration: Environmental error
> detected: Oracle Home is set to "E:\oracle\client_19_3" in the
> environment is different from Oracle Net Configuration Assistant
> installed Oracle Home.

and second, it appears that you do not have enough physical memory on your host to run a database:

> Status     : VERIFICATION_FAILED
> Name       : dexp
> Type       : Node
> Has Results: Yes
> Exp. value : 3,1543GB (3307520.0KB)
> Act. value : 1,1372GB (1192476.0KB)
> Info type  : StorageSize
> Info type  : StorageSize
>
> Errors  :
> PRVF-7562 : Sufficient available memory is not available on node "dexp" [Required available memory = 3230.0 MB]